# Confusion- What is the Difference between Apigee Api Gateway & Apigee Api Proxy? how to use gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, cloud, api-gateway, apigee

What is the Difference between Apigee Api Gateway and Apigee Api Proxy ?and how to use gateway?

how can I use apigee api gateway in my project of microservices or some full stack app ?

Is apigee api proxy same as apigee api gateway ? I could not found docs on apigee api gateway, Please help me on that

I am thinking of using api proxy as gateway in apigee but not crystal on that

Also I am getting confused with edge microgateway, is this the one which is apigee gateway here ?

Answer (score 2):

The names stick to the concept.

API Gateway, doesn't exist alone, it's the concept to have an interface between the API consumer and the backend.

The proxy is a way to implement the gateway. The proxy get the request from the consumer, check and transform it, and request to the backend(s). Finally, aggregate the answer(s) and send it to the consumer.

APIGee edge implement the concept of proxy, but the brand new APIGee X also.

Answer (score 1):

"Gateway" is a general concept, as is "Proxy". Both words are used in many forms in the networking industry, and to talk about integration. In my experience the word gateway is generally a broader concept, like a controlled entry point into a network, and a proxy usually means a specific implementation of come controls or handling of traffic.

In Google's Apigee product in particular, which is a whole suite of API-management capabilities, including what you might call a gateway capacity too, an API *Proxy* is a specific entity with a special definition. An Apigee proxy have a precise meaning in the Apigee product's model - it is a functional part of a chain of capabilities and infrastructure which defines how the overall deployment and integration work. An Apigee proxy as a specific product concept is explained here: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/understanding-apis-and-api-proxies

I doubt you will find docs which talk about "Apigee gateway" because Apigee doesn't define such a component specifically.

Apigee Edge Microgateway is one specific flavor of deployment for an Apigee proxy - meaning it is one of the runtime engines of several offered. Apigee Edge Microgateway is more or less defined as a "hybrid" option (it runs locally, not SaaS, but it still have a cloud dependency for startup and analytics collection with the Apigee Management Plane), is based on Node.js, and it is rather lean on features. Capable and extensible, but the main, full-featured Apigee proxy product/engine found in Apigee Edge (SaaS), Apigee X (SaaS), and Apigee Hybrid is more feature rich. Docs: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/microgateway/edge-microgateway-home